# ¿Cómo cargar un gif en un jLabel, no me funciona?

Tags: java, java-swing

llevo horas tratando de arreglar esto y no he podido, estoy tratando de cargar una animación de un dado girando, pero simplemente se queda la foto anterior y después se pone la png, que da el resultado del dado.

```java
String[] carasDado = {"dado1.png","dado2.png","dado3.png","dado4.png","dado5.png","dado6.png", "dado7.gif"};
        Random dado = new Random();
        int x = 0;
        int x2= 0;    
        ImageIcon dadoAnim; // Aqui inicio la variable donde voy a guardar la foto/gif

        if (seleccion == null) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debes apostar primero para jugar!");
        } else {

            if (tiradas < 2) {

                boolean jugando = true;

                // AQUI ESTA EL ERROR, no logro hacer que cargue el gif.
                dadoAnim =  new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(("/Imagenes/" + carasDado[6])));
                labDado.setIcon(dadoAnim);
```

Comment: debes de llamar a la imagen osea si esta en /Imagenes/dado.gif si no es imposible. has probado a meterlo por propiedades del labe es mas comodo

Comment: Si llamas directamente el .gif ¿Lo hace correctamente?

Comment: respondiendo a lo del directorio, efectivamente esta ahi, pero no logra cargar, y si, intente llamarlo directamente y tampoco anda MIENTO, lo acabo de probar y si funciona correctamente si lo llamo directamente

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez poniendo un repaint() después de insertar la imagen

```
labDado.setIcon(dadoAnim);
labDado.repaint();
```

Prueba esto y si no te funciona puedo pensar en otra opción.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tratar de ayudarme, pero lamentablemente no funciono, visualmente no carga el gif, pero siento que si lo hace ademas que no me tira ningun tipo de error.